# Apache SSL reverse proxy to a Embed Tomcat

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, mod-proxy, mod-ssl

I'm trying to put in place a reverse proxy for an application that is running a tomcat embed server over SSL. The application needs to run over SSL on the port 9002 so I have no way of "disabling SSL" for this app. The current setup schema looks like this:

```
[192.168.0.10:443 - Apache with mod_proxy] --> [192.168.0.10:9002 - Tomcat App]
```

After googling on how to make such a setup (and testing) I came across this:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssl/+bug/861137

Which lead to make my current configuration (to try to emulate the --secure-protocol=sslv3 option of wget)

```
/etc/apache2/sites/enabled/default-ssl:

<VirtualHost _default_:443>

    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile    /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key

    SSLProxyEngine On
    SSLProxyProtocol SSLv3
    SSLProxyCipherSuite SSLv3
    ProxyPass /test/ https://192.168.0.10:9002/
    ProxyPassReverse /test/ https://192.168.0.10:9002/

    LogLevel debug
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error-ssl.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access-ssl.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

The thing is that the error log is showing error:14077102:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unsupported protocol

Complete request log:

```
[Wed Mar 13 20:05:57 2013] [debug] mod_proxy.c(1020): Running scheme https handler (attempt 0)
[Wed Mar 13 20:05:57 2013] [debug] mod_proxy_http.c(1973): proxy: HTTP: serving URL https://192.168.0.10:9002/
[Wed Mar 13 20:05:57 2013] [debug] proxy_util.c(2011): proxy: HTTPS: has acquired connection for (192.168.0.10)
[Wed Mar 13 20:05:57 2013] [debug] proxy_util.c(2067): proxy: connecting https://192.168.0.10:9002/ to 192.168.0.10:9002
[Wed Mar 13 20:05:57 2013] [debug] proxy_util.c(2193): proxy: connected / to 192.168.0.10:9002
[Wed Mar 13 20:05:57 2013] [debug] proxy_util.c(2444): proxy: HTTPS: fam 2 socket created to connect to 192.168.0.10
[Wed Mar 13 20:05:57 2013] [debug] proxy_util.c(2576): proxy: HTTPS: connection complete to 192.168.0.10:9002 (192.168.0.10)
[Wed Mar 13 20:05:57 2013] [info] [client 192.168.0.10] Connection to child 0 established (server demo1agrubu01.demo.lab:443)
[Wed Mar 13 20:05:57 2013] [info] Seeding PRNG with 656 bytes of entropy
[Wed Mar 13 20:05:57 2013] [debug] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1866): OpenSSL: Handshake: start
[Wed Mar 13 20:05:57 2013] [debug] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1874): OpenSSL: Loop: before/connect initialization
[Wed Mar 13 20:05:57 2013] [debug] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1874): OpenSSL: Loop: unknown state
[Wed Mar 13 20:05:57 2013] [debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1897): OpenSSL: read 7/7 bytes from BIO#7f122800a100 [mem: 7f1230018f60] (BIO dump follows)
[Wed Mar 13 20:05:57 2013] [debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1830): +-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
[Wed Mar 13 20:05:57 2013] [debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1869): | 0000: 15 03 01 00 02 02 50                             ......P          |
[Wed Mar 13 20:05:57 2013] [debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1875): +-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
[Wed Mar 13 20:05:57 2013] [debug] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1903): OpenSSL: Exit: error in unknown state
[Wed Mar 13 20:05:57 2013] [info] [client 192.168.0.10] SSL Proxy connect failed
[Wed Mar 13 20:05:57 2013] [info] SSL Library Error: 336032002 error:14077102:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unsupported protocol
[Wed Mar 13 20:05:57 2013] [info] [client 192.168.0.10] Connection closed to child 0 with abortive shutdown (server example1.domain.tld:443)
[Wed Mar 13 20:05:57 2013] [error] (502)Unknown error 502: proxy: pass request body failed to 172.31.4.13:9002 (192.168.0.10)
[Wed Mar 13 20:05:57 2013] [error] [client 192.168.0.10] proxy: Error during SSL Handshake with remote server returned by /dsfe/
[Wed Mar 13 20:05:57 2013] [error] proxy: pass request body failed to 192.168.0.10:9002 (172.31.4.13) from 172.31.4.13 ()
[Wed Mar 13 20:05:57 2013] [debug] proxy_util.c(2029): proxy: HTTPS: has released connection for (172.31.4.13)
[Wed Mar 13 20:05:57 2013] [debug] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1884): OpenSSL: Write: SSL negotiation finished successfully
[Wed Mar 13 20:05:57 2013] [info] [client 192.168.0.10] Connection closed to child 6 with standard shutdown (server example1.domain.tld:443)
```

If I do a

```
wget --secure-protocol=sslv3 --no-check-certificate https://192.168.0.10:9002/
```

it works perfectly, but from apache is not working.

I'm on an Ubuntu Server with the latest updates running apache2 with mod_proxy and mod_ssl enabled:

```
~$ cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=12.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=precise
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS"

~# dpkg -s apache2
...
Version: 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.2
...

~# dpkg -s openssl
...
Version: 1.0.1-4ubuntu5.7
...
```

Hope that anyone may help

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you may want to try to edit the server.xml for your Tomcat application, and where the Connector port is defined, add something like:

```
proxyName="mysite.example.com" proxyPort="443" scheme="https" secure="true"
```

Comment: I can't freely modify the configuration of the Tomcat app :-(, but will try to see if this change solves the problem and get back to you

Comment: Proxy configuration on server.xml does not seem to work

Comment: One idea, make sure your 192.168.0.10 cert matches.  If you hit the Tomcat directly from say Firefox, do you get a certificate warning? Also, try with the bare minumum, remove the SSLv3 items if you can to test.

Comment: Without the SSLv3 items the error that I'm geeting is:

[Wed Mar 13 18:35:21 2013] [info] SSL Library Error: 336032824 error:14077438:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert internal error

Certificates comming from Tomcat are self generated but according to Apache 2 configuration, certificates are not checked by default

Comment: Ok, perhaps put the options back.  I think it would be good to share the server.xml entry for the https port.